# Parse Android Push Do not display notification

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I'm using Parse to send push messages to my app. In some cases I want to show a notification however in some cases I don't. For example when data should be updated I intend to send a notification to all devices so that way they don't have to poll. This should not show any notification.

Parse's GcmBroadcastReceiver seems to always generate a notification without any way of turning that off.

I'm also curious of how to stop Parse from auto-creating a notification because at some point I'm going to want to work with more complex notifications, which Parse doesn't support.

I've tried creating my own GcmBroadcastReceiver however when I did that I didn't receive anything. Maybe I rigged it wrong? Other than that how can I stop Parse SDK from auto-generating a notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Omit alert and title](https://parse.com/questions/can-i-customize-push-notification-of-android) from your push notification and the parse.com android SDK will not create a notification.